# Sum of (non-free) symmetric and asymmetric random matrices

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Consider random matrices $X,Y\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times P}$, i.e., $X_{ik}\sim{\cal N}(0,1/N)$ i.i.d. and likewise for $Y$.

- The eigenvalues of the symmetric covariance matrix $X^TX$ reside on the real line, follow the [Marchenko-Pastur distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution), and have support at $[\lambda_-, \lambda_+]$ for $\lambda_\pm=(1\pm\sqrt{\alpha})^2, \alpha=P/N$.
- The eigenvalues of the asymmetric matrix $X^TY$ are complex and follow the [Circular law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_law) for a circle of radius $\sqrt{\alpha}$ around the origin of the complex plane.

Can you say anything exact about the eigenvalues distribution of their (negative) sum:
$$X^TY-X^TX$$
If those $X^TX, X^TY$ were free (in the sense of Free Probability Theory), the distribution of the sum would have been a convolution of the two eigenvalue distributions and we could have calculated a formula for it in terms of their R-Transform. However, if I understand correctly, those are not free because of the common $X$ term.

Comment: Do you mean the symmetric covariance matrix **of** $X^TX$ has this distribution? Because i doubt the eigenvalues of $X^TX$ would be concentrated on a compact set, though I may be mistaken.

Comment: Yes, it is called marchenko pastur :) Eigenvalues of many randon matrices have support in a convex set!

Comment: I'm relatively sure that this only holds in the limit, as $N,P\to \infty$ with $P/N\to \alpha$, but not for finite $P,N$. Are you also asking for an asymptotic estimate for $X^TY-X^TX$?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in the limit $N,P\to\infty$ with $\alpha=P/N$; but it's a very good approximation also for small values (~100).